# Jquery dialog in MVC 3.0

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm newbie to Jquery. I've simple MVC View for employee registration and when user click on "Create Employee" button, i need to display Jquery confirmation dialog before actually hitting to controller action.

Can anybody please help, how i can use jquery dialog for doing the above task.

Thanks,
-Naren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html,

```
<div id='dialog-confirm'>Do you want to create an employee</div>
 <input type='buton'  value='create' onclick='CreateEmployee()'/>
```

in your javascript

```
function CreateEmployee(){
    $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');

}





    $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height:140,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Yes": function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                                         //call your create employee action here
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                }
            });
});
```

Comment: Jayantha, Thanks for the response. I've tried the same way, but modal dialog is not displaying. Can you please share complete code snippet. or step by step usage on MVC 3.0

Comment: can you post your code? I'll check what is wrong with it . Did you add references to jquery js files ?

Comment: may i know JS and CSS references added to your example.